# Protractor Login page and test end to end navigation

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am unable to run tests in protractor. I am a beginner and I trying to learn. I would be grateful, if any one helps me.

Conf.js

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.

  specs: [
    'Login_spec.js',
   // 'editprofile_spec.js',
  ],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 80000
  }
};
```

Spec.js

```
 describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
      it('should be able to login',function() {
        browser.get('http://www.example.com/login');
        element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('jackfedrick@gmail.com');
        element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('jack1234');
    });
     element(by.css('[ng-click="login()"]')).click();
    });
```

but i am getting the error ,

```
Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Any one please help me
```

Comment: check for ng-app attribute in <html> and <body> tags. If it is not in <body> tag. identify the css locator strategy for tag where ng-app is placed. and mention that css value as "rootElement:ccvalue" in conf.js file

Answer (score 0):

try moving to jasmine2 in your conf.js file.

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.

  specs: [
    'Login_spec.js',
   // 'editprofile_spec.js',
  ],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 80000
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your site is non Angular application.
You only access the webdriver instance by using **browser.driver**:

```
 browser.driver.get('http://www.example/player/#/login');
```

Comment: the site is actually angular :)